# PgAdmin3: Server doesn't listen

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin

I know it is common problem but so far I've tried pretty much everything(I'm using 3-1.18.1 version of pgadmin at Windows 8 and connecting to localhost:5432):
1)my hosts file includes lines

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

2) I have tried creating and loading postgressql.conf with following:

```
port = 5432
listenaddresses='*'
```

3) Reinstalling pgadmin (At first I was trying this with 1.20)

4) Turning off my Windows Firewall

5) Moving to another disc, so there won't be some permission denies.
Sad thing, I had this problem before, but after I made some work regarding data bases, I have completely reinstalled windows. No joy where I'm going wrong, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid. I needed to install postresql server itself.
As someone mentioned:

> pgAdmin is only a client tool. It does not include the database
>   server. It's the other way round: if you install the Postgres server
>   you usually also get the pgAdmin client. –  a_horse_with_no_name Jun 6
>   '14 at 11:40

Comment: This is kind of bloopers :D